# I need to read a name file and work on it after that like finding out his inode-number and other things

Tags: linux, shell

I read a name file, just the name and I need to print inode-number, the number of hard-links and others. How do I do that?
I thought initially to add the absolute path to my name file but I do not know how to that.

Comment: you can use 'ls -i ${fileName}' for your inode number, and 'find . -samefile ${fileName}' for the hard links.

Comment: i solved it with this variable acces=`stat -c %A $fisiername` , i need now to compare this variable with .....w... to se if group owner has accces for writing. how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `stat` command. Here is an example output:

```
UbuntuVBox:~/stackOver$ stat main.cpp
  File: ‘main.cpp’
  Size: 234         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 18749058    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   root)   Gid: ( 1000/   root)
Access: 2016-06-01 10:02:55.858362281 +0100
Modify: 2016-06-01 10:02:48.770820244 +0100
Change: 2016-06-01 10:02:48.782826244 +0100
 Birth: -
```

As you can see you get the inode number and number of links amongst other things.